# Rails 4 image-url scss helper returns wrong image path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I got in scss files few styles with background images:

```
> grep -r image-url app
app/assets/stylesheets/controls/player.css.scss:  background-image: image-url('armchair.jpg');
app/assets/stylesheets/controls/cards.css.scss:  background-image: image-url('cards.gif');
app/assets/stylesheets/play_section.css.scss:  background: image-url('table-grey.png') no-repeat center;
```

They render such css attributes respectively:

```
/assets/armchair.jpg
/images/cards.gif  <-- that one is wrong, it obviously returns 404
/assets/table-grey.png
```

What is wrong? I've searched the whole project for cards.gif and found the only line:

```
> grep -r cards.gif app lib
app/assets/stylesheets/controls/cards.css.scss:  background-image: image-url('cards.gif');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails will use `/assets/yourimage.ext` with the asset path helpers. If the image is not found in your assets folder, it will fall back to using `/images/yourimage.ext`.

Do you have this image in your assets folder? If not try adding it and under `app/assets/images/cards.gif` and check if it works.

Also make sure that you clear your `tmp/cache` folder by using `rake tmp:cache:clear`

Comment: I've double checked that cards.gif exists in app/assets/images folder. Moreover, if I change /images/cards.gif to /assets/cards.gif in style propery in firebug the image appears

Comment: Could you try clearing your tmp/cache folder `rake tmp:cache:clear` Also, it would help if you could add some debug to see what your asset_path is on a view by printing out `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` and also `asset_path('cards.gif')`

Comment: Yes! rake tmp:cache:clear helped!!! I accept. Could you move that advice from comment to the answer?